# Java - String Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting the following exception on the line where head is assigned and I'm not sure why:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 44`

When using "{1,2},3" as the value of `s`, running a debugger I can follow the loop and it is correctly assigning `commaSpot` to be 5 as I think it should. But for some reason `s.charAt(commaSpot))` doesn't think 5 is a valid index even though s is 7 characters long.

```
int commaSpot = 0;
int bracePairs = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   if(s.charAt(i) == '{') bracePairs++;
   if(s.charAt(i) == '}') bracePairs--;
   if(s.charAt(i) == ',' && bracePairs == 0) {
      commaSpot = i;
      break;
   }
}
head = s.substring(0, s.charAt(commaSpot));
tail = s.substring(s.charAt(commaSpot), s.length());
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using the result of `s.charAt(commaSpot)` as the second argument - rather than `commaSpot` itself. You want:

```
head = s.substring(0, commaSpot);
tail = s.substring(commaSpot, s.length());
```

You don't care about the value of the string at `commaSpot` - or rather, you know that it's a comma (Unicode value 44, hence the exception message). You care about the value of `commaSpot` itself, which is the place you want to split on.

Comment: Well now I feel dumb, thank you! And no, I do want the tail to include the comma, as I am simulating a parser which uses the CFG head -> set | number, tail -> , head tail | (nothing)

Comment: @user2816221: Okay - removed the last bit of the answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

In these line

```
head = s.substring(0, s.charAt(commaSpot));
tail = s.substring(s.charAt(commaSpot), s.length());
```

`s.charAt(commaSpot)` returns a `char` that is handled as an `int` for the index position. You want to use the actual index, which is `i`, so keep and use a copy of that value (`commaspot`).